# add_options_page() not working for some reason

Tags: wordpress

In my theme I created this folder called "theme-options" and inside it I created a file called "beex-theme-options.php" that has the following code:

```
function scheduler_admin_actions() {
    add_options_page(
        'Dump-It Scheduling', 
        'Dump-It Schedule', 
        'manage_options', 
        'Dump-It_Master_Schedule', 
        'my_callback'
    ); 
}
function my_callback()
{
    echo 'hello world';
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'scheduler_admin_actions');
```

However I don't see the menu item in dashboard when the theme is activated. I know the code is correct because I took it from another topic here just to be sure I don't have any errors in my original code but that's not it! 
I want to know why this is not working?

Thank you!!

Comment: it's work fine and menu added in Settings > Dump-It Schedule

Comment: It works when I move the code into my functions.php file but I wanted this on a separate folder.

Comment: So you need to include that file in function.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case it showing up nicely under settings menu and if you want it to make outside settings then you can add below code in functions.php

```
function scheduler_admin_actions() {
    add_menu_page( 'Dump-It Scheduling', 'Dump-It', 'manage_options', 'dump-it', 'dumpit_theme_create_page', 110 );
}

function dumpit_theme_create_page() {
    echo 'hello world';
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'scheduler_admin_actions');
```

Comment: Any idea why it doesn't work when it's called within my folder? It works when the code is moved to functions.php file.

Comment: its working fine bro.. i dont think you have included the file in functions.php   require get_template_directory() . '/theme-options/theme-options.php';  In your case  require get_template_directory() . '/theme-options/beex-theme-options.php';

Comment: That was it! Didn't include the file in functions.php file.. Do! Thank you.